# How to set seed or what we can do to make intercept constant in linear regression?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regression, apache-spark-mllib

I am creating a linear regression model in pyspark. but each time it give different intercept and weights . How to make constant ? I have used random.seed() but it is not working ? Anyone have any idea how to make constant intercept and weights in pyspark? Please give syntax or way how to handle this ?
I am using spark 1.4.2 and python 2.7 version.

```python
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression 
from pyspark.sql.types import *
seed = 42
train_df, test_df = miles_new_df.randomSplit( [0.7, 0.3], seed = seed )
linreg = LinearRegression(maxIter=500,regParam=0.0) #modelparameters
lm = linreg.fit( train_df )  #fitting
lm.intercept
lm.weights
```

Comment: Linear regression coefficients are deterministic. If you're getting different results, it means you must be fitting to different data. Can you try to provide an [mcve] that demonstrates your issue? At least show us how you define `train_df`.

Comment: @pault but if i will run twice linreg.fit(on same data).How it can give two different intercept ?Data is same.

Comment: It should not. Can you create an [mcve] with some sample data that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: Your linear regression is computing the weights using gradient descent, so it should be a problem related to the parameters regarding gradient descent and not the dataset, for example the initial weights you begin with, or the number of iterations before you reach convergence. For example, in neural network you usually start with random weights and this yields into different predictions. I tried to reproduce your error using `LinearRegressionWithSGD` (similar to Pyspark version) and some dummy data but I get the same weights and intercept. If possible try to share your data (or part of it)

Comment: @user322778 Thanks , was doing a bit mistake.Can you help me how to save the regresion model .there is nothing available https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression and model.save(sc,"path") is not working

Answer (score -1):

You can set seed while training you model with pyspark.